# Excluding files of a certain size

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate a .csv file that lists all .txt file in a sub-directory but can exclude a .txt file of a certain size.

Without an if statement around file size, I can successfully generate the .csv file list that has the full paths to the .txt files (1105 files total)

```
import os
import csv
import os.path
mtn_path = "TEXT_FILE_PATH\\"
a = open(mtn_path + "output.csv", 'w+', newline='')
num_files = 0
for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mtn_path):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".txt")]:
#       if os.stat(filename).st_size > 20000:
            f = os.path.join(path, filename)
            a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
            num_files = num_files + 1
)
#
print("The total number of text files found was " + str(num_files))
```

When I include the if os.stat line, I get the error:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'INT_NR_H1000Cu_000.mtn_001.txt'

That particular .txt file is the first one listed in the csv file of the working code.

Comment: `filename` is just the file name, you need to pass the full path to `os.stat`.

Comment: Thank you.  I replaced the code and used "f" in the if os.path file and placed it before the .write command and it looks like it's working now; down to the 553 files as hoped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the full path to `os.stat`. Rearrange your code a bit:

```
for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".txt")]:
    f = os.path.join(path, filename)
    if os.stat(f).st_size > 20000:
        a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
        num_files = num_files + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include the full path in the `if` statement. os.path can't find `filename`

Add full path to the file
`os.path.join(path, filename)`

Also delete that slash at the end of `TEXT_FILE_PATH`

```
import os
import csv
import os.path
mtn_path = r"TEXT_FILE_PATH"
a = open(mtn_path + "output.csv", 'w+', newline='')
num_files = 0
for path, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(mtn_path):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".txt")]:       
        if os.stat(os.path.join(path, filename)).st_size > 20000:
            f = os.path.join(path, filename)
            a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
            num_files = num_files + 1
)
#
print("The total number of text files found was " + str(num_files))
```